# Evolution - imported signatures not used

Tags: configuration, evolution, signature

Evolution 3.28.0-4 on Debian Testing.

I did a restore of my evolution-config, copied ~/.config/evolution from backup to my machine. The email-accounts and all the emails are fine.

For each account there is a signature assigned - I can see this in settings. But the signatures are not attached to the emails I write.

In ~/.config/evolution/signatures I see four files (hashes as names) with html-code of signatures inside.

Any ideas how to "activate" those signatures, to be attached to my emails?

Best regards
Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The signature-files had wrong file-permissions. They had 755 instead of 644!

Just did a chmod 644 056xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and the signature worked immedently.

Best regards